# Poisson process question - calls arriving.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Assume the number of calls per hour arriving at an answering service follows a Poisson process with $\lambda = 4$.

Question: If it is know that $8$ calls came in the first two hours.  What is the probability that exactly five arrived in the first hour?

Attempt: Isn't this just a combinatorial question?  So the answer is ${8 \choose 5}/2^8$

Comment: The answer is indeed the one you wrote. It can be obtained either the quick way you found, or by a formal conditional probability calculation.